# WCF Service and Concurrency

Tags: wcf, iis, concurrency

I have a driver that I need to access via a web site that is not thread-safe. Since many people can be on the site at a given time I figured I would create a WCF service that would handle all the calls. Most of the calls would be asynchronous calls to add items to a work queue. Some would be synchronous calls to get a list of items still unprocessed or items that have been processed.

Since the driver isn't thread safe, the service must take in potentially many requests at once and either add items to the work queue, return the work queue, or return the work-completed queue. A single-threaded operation in the service needs to read from the work queue, processes the job using this non-thread-safe driver, and, when complete, update the work-completed queue.

While I conceptually have clear in my mind what to do, the specifics of implementation confuse me a little. I think I should host the service in IIS since it will have to respond to web requests and otherwise act like any other web site, but I'm not sure how to guarantee that the access of the driver will remain single-threaded without blocking web requests. Do I need a second service, perhaps a Windows service, that would process all access to the driver and use the IIS-hosted WCF service to get the next queue item and update the queue when processing is complete?

Comment: What kind of driver are you using that is required to be used on your server?  Honestly, that would scare me a little bit.

Comment: It is for a very old legacy system. There is another driver that I could use, but it would require lots of other changes that I'd prefer not to make if I can avoid it. In either case I'm going to have to write the web service and I'd like to leverage the existing single-threaded code for this job that I already have.

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider:

1. Clients call your aspx pages,
2. Pages call to wcf service (netMsmqBinding)? - to avoid blocking and waiting (singke service, can be hosted where you want).
3. When server done - it's notify clients (websocket? SignalR?)